# Get magento2 categories with restsharp rest API

Tags: c#, magento, magento2, restsharp

I'm pretty new to magento restsharp Rest API. I just managed to get an admin access token. The next step for me is to receive te magento categories but I don't really get the way of working with the rest api commands. I think I need to use this one: `GET    /V1/categories`
I just don't know how to use it. I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me out with this.

Maybe good to know:
Visual Studio 2017
Rest API
C# (restsharp)
oauth2
magento 2

I don't know how to use the admin token I receive at the end of the static void.

my code thus far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Base URL needs to be Specified
            String host = "http://beta.topprice24.com";
            //Relative URL needs to be Specified
            String endpoint = "/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token";

            RestClient _restClient = new RestClient(host);
            var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.POST);

            //Initialize Credentials Property
            var userRequest = new Credentials { username = "blabla", password = "blabla" };
            var inputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);

            //Request Header
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            //Request Body
            request.AddParameter("application/json", inputJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = _restClient.Execute(request);

            var token = response.Content;
        }

        public void getCategories()
        {
            String host = "http://beta.topprice24.com";
            String endpoint = "/rest/V1/categories";
            String token = "Bearer " + magento acces token?;

            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(host);

            var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
            var rawResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
            var responseBody = rawResponse.Content;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please update with tried piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer based on the updated question code:

**Modified Code:**

```
  public String getCategories(String adminToken)
    {
        String host = "http://beta.topprice24.com";
        String endpoint = "rest/V1/categories";
        String token = "Bearer " +adminToken;

        RestClient restClient = new RestClient(host);

        var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
        var rawResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
        return rawResponse.Content;
    }
```

In your main function you can call the method as below

**Modified Main Function:**

```
        request.AddParameter("application/json", inputJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = _restClient.Execute(request);

        var token = response.Content;
        var categoriesResult=getCategories(token);
        Console.WriteLine("Categories List :" + categoriesResult);
```

Comment: is this the correct way?  
public void getCategories()
        {
            String host = "http://beta.topprice24.com";
            String endpoint = "/V1/categories";
            String token = "Bearer " + Token;

            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(host);

            var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
            var rawResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
            var responseBody = rawResponse.Content;
        }

Comment: Please use the baseURI as http://beta.topprice24.com and endpoint  as rest/V1/categories

Comment: Could you check the code please. And it's a bit weird because when requesting the token I used http://beta.topprice24.com as host.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the updated question.Please check

Comment: This might sound stupid but I don't really understand where to put the code. which code do I need to put in de client(project) class and which code do I need to put in the Magento(project) class?

Comment: you can add both the main and getCategories function in the client project and check

Comment: I get this error message at getCategories : var getCategories(token);.
this is the error message: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ‘Program.getCategories(string)’

Comment: So I changed public String getCategories(String adminToken) into a static string which solved the problem. But now it says I'm not authorized to access..

Comment: Can you try access the URI manually with the generated admin token?

Comment: if you could show me how to do this?:P
I'm very sorry for being such a burden but I can't find a proper tutorial anywhere.

Comment: Sample POSTMAN Steps were mentioned in https://support.brightcove.com/use-postman-api-requests. Please check and You can skip the step 7 to 11 and add the header ( Key : Authorization, Value: Bearer <<Token>>)

Comment: I get the same error as in visual studio: Consumer is not authorized to access %resources